# Single sign on between two wordpress website

Tags: single-sign-on

I have two wordpress website 
Ex:abc.com and xyz.abc.com (both are in wordpress).

i want to implement single sign on(SSO) into this two website without using **multisite** functionality.

Comment: This plugin may be suitable for what you want. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-sso/

Comment: Thank you for reponse
This plugin use multisite concept but my requirement is different i  want implement single sing on without multisite concept
if i use multisite then my site url will change that i dont want
Ex:abc.com (Main Site) other wordpress site xyz.abc.com

Comment: If you want to keep the websites completely separated, you can with [WP Remote Users Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-remote-users-sync/advanced/) (disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that we have two websites, mentioned in your question - `abc.com`, `xyz.abc.com`, and their table prefixes are - `ab_`, `xy_`.

#### Requirements

Both websites must be installed within the same domain. Both websites must share the same database using different table prefixes. Both websites must share user tables ( ex. `ab_users`, `ab_usermeta` ).

#### Websites' wp-config.php files

The `wp-config.php` files of both websites should be identical, with one exception, `$table_prefix` for `abc.com` website should be `ab_`, and for `xyz.abc.com` should be `xy_`. See `wp-config.php` for `abc.com`, below:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'abc'); // change it, to match your installation  

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'abcadmin'); // change it, to match your installation

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database pasword here'); // change it, to match your installation

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // change it, to match your installation

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',              'use generated value here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',       'use generated value here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',         'use generated value here');
define('NONCE_KEY',             'use generated value here');

define('AUTH_SALT',             'use generated value here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT',      'use generated value here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',        'use generated value here');
define('NONCE_SALT',            'use generated value here');

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN',         '.abc.com');
define('COOKIEPATH',            '/');
define('COOKIEHASH',            md5('abc.com'));

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'ab_'; // in wp-config.php for xyz.abc.com change it to 'xy_'

/* uncomment these two lines after successful website installation */
// define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'ab_users');
// define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'ab_usermeta');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

#### New installations

Create an empty database to be used by both installations.

Drop `wp-config.php` for `abc.com` to the root of `abc.com` and do the installation. Do not login to your website, yet. Write down administrator's user name and password.

Drop `wp-config.php` for `xyz.abc.com` to the root of `xyz.abc.com` and do the installation. Do not login to your new website.

In both websites, create `mu-plugins` folder in `/wp-content`, if it does not exist.

Make `fpw-sync-users.php` file with the following content:

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: FPW Synchronize Shared Users
  Author: Frank P. Walentynowicz
  Author URI: https://fw2s.com
  Disclaimer: Use at your own risk. No warranty expressed or implied is provided.
 */

// Users synchronization on admin login
function fpw_synchronize_admins_on_admin_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'administrator', $user->caps ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $site_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $admins_only = true;

        $other_prefixes = array(
            'xy_',
        );

        $args = array( 
            'fields'    => 'ID',
        );
        if ( $admins_only )
            $args[ 'role' ] = 'administrator';

        $users = get_users( $args );

        foreach ( $users as $id ) {
            $cap = get_user_meta( $id, $site_prefix . 'capabilities', true );

            foreach ( $other_prefixes as $prefix )
                update_user_meta( $id, $prefix . 'capabilities', $cap );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'fpw_synchronize_admins_on_admin_login', 10, 2 );

// User synchronization on admin create user
function fpw_synchronize_user_on_admin_register( $id ) {
    $me = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( array_key_exists( 'administrator', $me->caps ) ) {
        $other_prefixes = array(
            'xy_',
        );
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $id );
        $cap = $user->caps;
        foreach ( $other_prefixes as $prefix )
            update_user_meta( $id, $prefix . 'capabilities', $cap );
    }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'fpw_synchronize_user_on_admin_register', 10, 1 );

// User synchronization on profile update
function fpw_synchronize_user_on_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        $other_prefixes = array(
            'xy_',
        );
        $cap = array( $_POST[ 'role' ] => true, );
        foreach ( $other_prefixes as $prefix )
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix . 'capabilities', $cap );
    }
 }
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'fpw_synchronize_user_on_profile_update');
```

Drop `fpw-sync-users.php` file to `/wp-content/mu-plugins` folder of both websites.

Modify `fpw-sync-users.php` file for `xyz.abc.com`, by replacing every occurence of:

```
$other_prefixes = array(
    'xy_',
);
```

with:

```
$other_prefixes = array(
    'ab_',
);
```

Modify `wp-config.php` files for both websites, by uncommenting these two defines:

```
// define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'ab_users');
// define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'ab_usermeta');
```

All done. Login to `abc.com` and go to `xyz.abc.com`. You will be logged in to this website, as well.

You can drop `xy_users` and `xy_usermeta` tables from the database, because they will not be used, anymore.

#### Existing installations

Things are getting slightly more complicated, when we deal with already existing websites, with separate databases.

**Important**: make a backup of wp-config.php files, and databases, of both websites, before proceeding!

Let's use the database of `abc.com` website as a shared database. We have to export all tables ( except `users` and `usermeta` ) from `xyz.abc.com` database, and import them into `abc.com` database.

Make sure that table prefix for `xyz.abc.com` database is different from table prefix for `abc.com` database. If it is different, you can skip the following procedure of changing table prefix for xyz.abc.com.

**Change table prefix for `xyz.abc.com`**: install and activate [WP Prefix Changer](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-prefix-changer/) plugin. Run its procedure to change the prefix. Deactivate and delete this plugin. Now you are ready for export / import tables.

Export tables from `xyz.abc.com` database, and import them into `abc.com` database. For this, you can use `phpMyAdmin`, or any other tool available.

Modify `wp-config.php` ( see `wp-config.php` example from **New installations** section ) for `abc.com`, by adding the following defines:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN',         '.abc.com');
define('COOKIEPATH',            '/');
define('COOKIEHASH',            md5('abc.com'));
```

and

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'ab_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'ab_usermeta');
```

Modify `wp-config.php` for `xyz.abc.com`, by replacing database related defines, to match your shared database values. Add defines, you just added to `wp-config.php` of `abc.com`. Replace *keys* and *hashes* defines, to match these defines in `wp-config.php` for `abc.com`.

Add ( as described in **New installations** section ) `fpw-sync-users.php` synchronization plugin to `/wp-content/mu-plugins` folders of both websites, and modify its prefixes accordingly.

That's it. Now you have shared users, who can use SSO.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response

I have implemented your code i am able to login with single table in both website

but when i login in abc.com it wont login in xyz.abc.com

Comment: I am implementing your code in localhost will that will be work in localhost,
if yes then what should i specify in COOKIE_DOMAIN field path of my file like "localhost/test/abc.com"????

Comment: To be honest, I've never used it on 'localhost'. I don't know. You might try '.localhost' ( note the dot in front of main domain ), but I cannot guarantee it. Even my dev environments are on standard domains. I've implementations on several production sites.

Comment: some how i manage to create virtual host and as you mention  COOKIE_DOMAIN i have implemented that with abc.com and xyz.abc.com but i am facing problem in that once i login in abc.com it wont automatically login in xyz.abc.com and if i login in xyz.abc.com mannually automatically logged out in abc.com

Comment: Did you try `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN','.abc.com');`? Did you make aliases in local hosts? I'm trying to install XAMPP on my Windows 10 for testing. I'll try to test it there. I need some time as I'm busy now.

Comment: yes i have define COOKIE_DOMAIN and also created aliases of the domain but its not working..

Comment: Hello  @Frank P. Walentynowicz
after a lot of hardword i have successfully done SSO using your solution mention above

Comment: Great. I'm glad it works.

Comment: Could you please edit your question removing the line about plugin? This will remove hold status of your question.

Comment: I believe I followed your instructions correct. But I am not able to log into both sites from site ab.  the cookie domain is defined as ('COOKIE_DOMAIN','.abc.com')  Both of my sites are on subdomains, so I am defining this as .ab.mysite.com and .xy.mysite.com    Could this be where I am erring?