# Wordpress automatic Login on other page?

Tags: multisite, database, users, login

I have a littlee questions about Wordpress.

If I have several sites on one Webserver and all pages use the same "user table" and "user meta table", can I make if one user login on site one and then go to site two that the user automatically login on site two? If yes, how I can make this?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Read my answer to similar question, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/single-sign-on-between-two-wordpress-website/272208#272208). This answer provides a solution for two sites, but can be used for any number of sites.