# Single Sign On (SSO) between two Wordpress websites

Tags: users, user-registration

Not having much luck finding solutions here, can someone help?

I have abc.com, and sub.abc.com

Users will create an account on abc.com, but I need users to login with to sub.abc.com after. If users can automatically be logged in, that's a bonus. I don't mind if they need to login again when going to sub.abc.com, but I they shouldn't need to create an account.

Thanks!

Comment: probably the best way is use a single database for both WP installs and then share the user table: https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/

Comment: You'll find a detailed solution in my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/single-sign-on-between-two-wordpress-website/272208#272208)